# Getting output from Perl script called from Java code

Tags: java, perl

I've read a lot of questions/examples on this issue, but unfortunately I have not been able to solve my problem. I need to call a Perl script (that I cannot change) from Java code, and then I need to get the output from that script.

The script is used to take student programming homework assignments, and check them for copying by comparing all of them together. The script can take ~45 seconds to run, but only requires the arguments to be properly formatted, there is no interactivity.

My issue is when I call the script from my Java code I get the first line of output from the script but nothing else. I'm using Runtime.exe() and then waitFor() to wait for the script to finish. However the waitFor() function returns before the script actually finishes. I don't know any Perl so I'm not sure if the script is doing something that 'confuses' the java Process object, or if there's an issue in my code.

```
        Process run = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
        output = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(run.getInputStream()));

        run.waitFor();

        String temp;
        while((temp = output.readLine()) != null){
            System.out.println(temp);
        }
```

The Perl script..

```
use IO::Socket;

#
# As of the date this script was written, the following languages were supported.  This script will work with
# languages added later however.  Check the moss website for the full list of supported languages.
#
@languages = ("c", "cc", "java", "ml", "pascal", "ada", "lisp", "scheme", "haskell", "fortran", "ascii", "vhdl", "perl", "matlab", "python", "mips", "prolog", "spice", "vb", "csharp", "modula2", "a8086", "javascript", "plsql", "verilog");

$server = 'moss.stanford.edu';
$port = '7690';
$noreq = "Request not sent.";
$usage = "usage: moss [-x] [-l language] [-d] [-b basefile1] ... [-b basefilen] [-m #] [-c \"string\"] file1 file2 file3 ...";

#
# The userid is used to authenticate your queries to the server; don't change it!
#
$userid=[REDACTED];

#
# Process the command line options.  This is done in a non-standard
# way to allow multiple -b's.
#
$opt_l = "c";   # default language is c
$opt_m = 10;
$opt_d = 0;
$opt_x = 0;
$opt_c = "";
$opt_n = 250;
$bindex = 0;    # this becomes non-zero if we have any base files

while (@ARGV && ($_ = $ARGV[0]) =~ /^-(.)(.*)/) {
    ($first,$rest) = ($1,$2);  

    shift(@ARGV);
    if ($first eq "d") {
        $opt_d = 1;
        next;
    }
    if ($first eq "b") {
        if($rest eq '') {
            die "No argument for option -b.\n" unless @ARGV;
            $rest = shift(@ARGV);
        }
        $opt_b[$bindex++] = $rest;
        next;
    }
    if ($first eq "l") {
        if ($rest eq '') {
            die "No argument for option -l.\n" unless @ARGV;
            $rest = shift(@ARGV);
        }
        $opt_l = $rest;
        next;
    }
    if ($first eq "m") {
        if($rest eq '') {
            die "No argument for option -m.\n" unless @ARGV;
            $rest = shift(@ARGV);
        }
        $opt_m = $rest;
        next;
    }
    if ($first eq "c") {
        if($rest eq '') {
            die "No argument for option -c.\n" unless @ARGV;
            $rest = shift(@ARGV);
        }
        $opt_c = $rest;
        next;
    }
    if ($first eq "n") {
        if($rest eq '') {
            die "No argument for option -n.\n" unless @ARGV;
            $rest = shift(@ARGV);
        }
        $opt_n = $rest;
        next;
    }
    if ($first eq "x") {
        $opt_x = 1;
        next;
    }
    #
    # Override the name of the server.  This is used for testing this script.
    #
    if ($first eq "s") {
        $server = shift(@ARGV);
        next;
    }
    #
    # Override the port.  This is used for testing this script.
    #
    if ($first eq "p") {
        $port = shift(@ARGV);
        next;
    }
    die "Unrecognized option -$first.  $usage\n";
}

#
# Check a bunch of things first to ensure that the
# script will be able to run to completion.
#

#
# Make sure all the argument files exist and are readable.
#
print "Checking files . . . \n";
$i = 0;
while($i < $bindex)
{
    die "Base file $opt_b[$i] does not exist. $noreq\n" unless -e "$opt_b[$i]";
    die "Base file $opt_b[$i] is not readable. $noreq\n" unless -r "$opt_b[$i]";
    die "Base file $opt_b is not a text file. $noreq\n" unless -T "$opt_b[$i]";
    $i++;
}
foreach $file (@ARGV)
{
    die "File $file does not exist. $noreq\n" unless -e "$file";
    die "File $file is not readable. $noreq\n" unless -r "$file";
    die "File $file is not a text file. $noreq\n" unless -T "$file";
}

if ("@ARGV" eq '') {
    die "No files submitted.\n $usage";
}
print "OK\n";

#
# Now the real processing begins.
#


$sock = new IO::Socket::INET (
                                  PeerAddr => $server,
                                  PeerPort => $port,
                                  Proto => 'tcp',
                                 );
die "Could not connect to server $server: $!\n" unless $sock;
$sock->autoflush(1);

sub read_from_server {
    $msg = <$sock>;
    print $msg;
}

sub upload_file {
    local ($file, $id, $lang) = @_;
#
# The stat function does not seem to give correct filesizes on windows, so
# we compute the size here via brute force.
#
    open(F,$file);
    $size = 0;
    while (<F>) {
        $size += length($_);
    }
    close(F);

    print "Uploading $file ...";
    open(F,$file);
    $file =~s/\s/\_/g;    # replace blanks in filename with underscores
    print $sock "file $id $lang $size $file\n";
    while (<F>) {
        print $sock $_;
    }
    close(F);
    print "done.\n";
}


print $sock "moss $userid\n";      # authenticate user
print $sock "directory $opt_d\n";
print $sock "X $opt_x\n";
print $sock "maxmatches $opt_m\n";
print $sock "show $opt_n\n";

#
# confirm that we have a supported languages
#
print $sock "language $opt_l\n";
$msg = <$sock>;
chop($msg);
if ($msg eq "no") {
    print $sock "end\n";
    die "Unrecognized language $opt_l.";
}


# upload any base files
$i = 0;
while($i < $bindex) {
    &upload_file($opt_b[$i++],0,$opt_l);
}

$setid = 1;
foreach $file (@ARGV) {
    &upload_file($file,$setid++,$opt_l);
}

print $sock "query 0 $opt_c\n";
print "Query submitted.  Waiting for the server's response.\n";
&read_from_server();
print $sock "end\n";
close($sock);
```

Thank you for any input you may have on my problem.

Comment: What is the value of `cmd`?

Comment: How do you know that it's returning before the script finishes? It seems more likely to me that what's happening is that it's finishing, but since you didn't grab the script's stdout right after launching it, you don't see its output. Instead of running `waitFor`, just immediately grab `run.getInputStream()` and then call `waitFor` in your cleanup to ensure that it's terminated.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention I know that it's returning before the script finishes because I have an message box appear when waitFor() returns, and that box is appearing almost instantly after the script starts. I tried your idea of calling waitFor() after grabbing the output, but it still returns before the script finishes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use my native [Java client for MOSS instead](https://github.com/nordicway/moji) .

Don't mind the version number. I've been using it in production successfully.